# SMD Schottky diode part number from marking code

Tags: schottky

I can't find the part number from marking code. I think it's a schottky diode.

Marking is:

94B

1L2

D1 & D2 have the same marking code.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE!  Googling "1L2 schottky" turned up some promising results.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an ST [STPS1L20M](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stps1l20m.pdf) 1A 20V Schottky diode.

[image]